# Избавление от SQL запросов  в цикле

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Всем привет.

Мне нужно удалить выбранные сообщения из бд. Админ выбирает их (отмечает нужные чекбоксы), а потом они отправляются на сервер в виде массива. Всё норм, но дело в том, что удаление происходит в цикле. Сам код:

```
$check = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($id_elements); $i++) {
    if ($db->query("DELETE FROM `messages` WHERE `id` = " . intval($id_elements[$i])))
        $check++;
}
if ($check == count($id_elements)) {
    echo 'удалены все выделенные записи';
} else {
    echo 'Ошибка';
}
```

Но все мы знаем, что запросы в цикле это не хорошо, поэтому прошу подсказать, как можно выполнить удаление одним запросом?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(is_array($_POST['id_elements'])){
    $id_elements = implode(',',$_POST['id_elements']);
}
$db->query("DELETE FROM `messages` WHERE `id` IN ($id_elements)")
```

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так:

```
foreach($id_elements as $key => $value)
{
    $id_elements[$key] = intval($value)
}
if($db->query("DELETE FROM `messages` WHERE `id` IN ('".implode("','", $id_elements)."')")
{
      echo 'удалены все выделенные записи';
}
else 
{
      echo 'Ошибка';
}
```